How to plot ellipse centered at weighted mean incorporating 95% of data mass - ideally in Matlab
I'm using Matlab 2022a to solve this problem, but if anyone has general equations/algorithms or a good solution in another program (e.g. R), I'd be interested in hearing about that too.
I have a set of spatial data (mock data generated and plotted below) with x,y, and a third column of data values at each location.
num = 100;
P = mvnrnd([0,0,20], [ 11.3669 -2.9268 -2.0568;
-2.9268 1.3372 0.4483;
-2.0568 0.4483 51.9697],num);
CenterofMass=sum(P(:,1:2).*P(:,3))/sum(P(:,3)); %weighted mean
scatter(P(:,1),P(:,2),abs(P(:,3))), hold on
plot(CenterofMass(:,1),CenterofMass(:,2),'r+')


mock data
I'm trying to

Calculate and plot an ellipse centered at the center of mass (weighted mean), with axes that incorporate a statistical percent (e.g. 95%) of the data mass (in the third column).

I've looked at this discussion, but it doesn't deal with having data values at locations.
Calculating the center of mass is relatively easy, but I'm struggling with how to deal with the spatial covariance (of whatever equivalent is needed) of data with weights.

The first thing to do would be to come up with a clear definition of what you mean by "a statistical percent (e.g. 95%) of the data mass". Do you have constraints in execution time? If not, you can reuse the exact code that you linked, and just play with the scale factor. You could also "cheat" and just have x points of mass 1 where a point of mass x is present in your data

The idea is to tweak your data so that you can use the excellent answer from the post you linked to.
Instead of having a set of points with different masses, you can create a set of points with equal mass, by scaling the number of points:
num = 100;
P = mvnrnd([0,0,20], [ 11.3669 -2.9268 -2.0568;
    -2.9268 1.3372 0.4483;
    -2.0568 0.4483 51.9697],num);
CenterofMass=sum(P(:,1:2).*P(:,3))/sum(P(:,3)); %weighted mean
scatter(P(:,1),P(:,2),abs(P(:,3))), hold on
plot(CenterofMass(:,1),CenterofMass(:,2),'r+')

% Create array X
% digits kept (mass is not an integer)
prec = 2;
nX = round(10^prec*P(:,3));
X = [];

for ii=1:size(P,1)

    % Each point is repeated nX(ii) times to get correct mass
    X = [X;[P(ii,1),P(ii,2)].*ones(nX(ii),1)];

end

Now, you can just use the code from the answer, using the EDIT part as well:
Mu = mean( X );
X0 = bsxfun(@minus, X, Mu);

STD = 2;                     %# 2 standard deviations
conf = 2*normcdf(STD)-1;     %# covers around 95% of population
% --> In the tweaked dataset X, this is equivalent to 95% of the mass
scale = chi2inv(conf,2); 

%# eigen decomposition [sorted by eigen values]
[V,D] = eig(scale* (X0'*X0) ./ (size(X,1)-1) );     %#' cov(X0)
[D,order] = sort(diag(D), 'descend');
D = diag(D);
V = V(:, order);

t = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
e = [cos(t) ; sin(t)];        %# unit circle
VV = V*sqrt(D);               %# scale eigenvectors
e = bsxfun(@plus, VV*e, Mu'); %#' project circle back to orig space

%# plot cov and major/minor axes
plot(e(1,:), e(2,:), 'Color','k');



Thanks Bilbokeey!
I was confused at first by how one could create a set of equal points without losing necessary precision, so I was at first thinking you meant to just round to the nearest integer.  But the lines
prec = 2;
nX = round(10^prec*P(:,3));
allow me to maintain whatever level of precision I desire by changing prec.  Brilliant!
Execution time is not a serious constraint, so this solution will work well for me.
Thanks again!
Rebecca

Good solution. Another solution is to use the weighted covariance.

Thank you, and thanks for the interesting link! I was not aware of that
